# Unable to generate a Cashier PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5 to generate a PDF from a subscription generated from [Cashier](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing#invoices).  The docs say this is as simple as calling:

```
return $user->downloadInvoice($invoice->id, [
    'vendor'  => 'Your Company',
    'product' => 'Your Product',
]);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an odd error:

```
No hint path defined for [cashier]
```

The code I am actually using is as follows:

```
Route::get('billing/invoices/download/{id}', function($id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    //$invoice = $user->invoices()->find($id);
    return $user->downloadInvoice($id, [
        'vendor'  => 'Certify Me',
        //'product' => $invoice->lines->data[0]['plan']->name,
        'product' => 'Subscription',
    ]);
});
```

The [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing#invoices) make me assume that the PDF is automatically generated.  I'd then assume I could override the PDF layout if I chose to.

Comment: I am on Laravel 4.2 and the invoices are simply html. Even though the documentation states: "Use the downloadInvoice method to generate a PDF download of the invoice. Yes, it's really this easy:"

Comment: It's definitely a PDF on 5.  The code is referencing some PDF libs too

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this (L5.1, Cashier 6.0). This seems to be caused by the service provider not being correctly loaded.

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Check that you have added the correct service provider, at the time of writing that is `Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider` to your `config/app.php`
2. If it still doesn't work, go run `php artisan config:clear` to make sure that the service provider is picked up.

Happy invoicing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to resurrect this beast.

I had a similar issue because the service provider was not loaded.  If you checkout CashierServiceProvider you'll see it adds the necessary 'namespace' for the 'cashier' prefixed views.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../views', 'cashier');

    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../../views' => base_path('resources/views/vendor/cashier'),
    ]);
}
```

Add `Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider` to your `config/app.php` file and inside the `providers` key.

For anyone who runs across this like we did.